# Getting the height and width of a polygon on a certain plane

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I'm currently using the following to apply a texture to a polygon formed by TriangleList

```
public static VertexPositionColorTexture[] TextureMapping(VertexPositionColorTexture[] vertices, float xScale, float yScale)
    {
        bool initialized = false;

        float x, y;
        float lX = 0, hX = 0, lY = 0, hY = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {

            x = vertices[i].Position.X;
            y = vertices[i].Position.Y;

            if (!initialized)
            {
                hX = x;
                lX = x;
                hX = y;
                hY = y;

                initialized = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (x > hX)
                {
                    hX = x;
                }
                else if (x < lX)
                {
                    lX = x;
                }

                if (y > hY)
                {
                    hY = y;
                }
                else if (y < lY)
                {
                    lY = y;
                }
            }


        }

        float width = (Math.Abs(lX) + Math.Abs(hX)) / xScale;
        float height = (Math.Abs(lY) + Math.Abs(hY)) / yScale;

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i].TextureCoordinate.X = vertices[i].Position.X / width;
            vertices[i].TextureCoordinate.Y = vertices[i].Position.Y / height;
        }

        return vertices;
```

This currently works fine for a polygon that has points that all have Z=0 (example: (0,0,0) (0,10,0) (10,10,0) (10,0,0)) but doesn't work for any that are rotated or not flat along the z (example (0,0,0) (0,0,10) (0,10,10) (0,10,0)). The only solution I have come with is to get the plane that the polygon lies on (it will always be flat) and somehow rotate or translate the vertices in the above method to flatten it to the xy line to allow for the correct height and width to be determined. Anyone point me in the right direction, or suggest something else?

Comment: The polygon lying in the xz-plane is probably one of the two cases that don't work (the other is the polygon lying in the yz-plane). That's because there is no extent in one of the directions. Therefore, you can't really define "up" and "right". How do you want to apply the texture on the polygon? It can be rotated somehow after all. You can check if width or height is 0 and use the z extent instead. Btw, the calculation of width and height looks a bit strange. Shouldn't it be `hX - lX`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself by re-writing and rotating the polygon to the z plane.